# Django and time zone

Tags: python, django, datetime, pytz

Django 1.7, PostgreSQL.

I want to store datetime in UTC and display it in PST time zone.

My local time: 8:05 am

UTC time: 1:05 am

PST time: 6:05 pm

Django doc:

```
When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores date and time 
information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects 
internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates 
and forms.
```

setting.py

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific'
```

Model field

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have created new model, and in django admin it display PST time (6:05 pm). It is OK. But if I do:

```
select created_at from my_table where id = 1;
```

It display my local time (8:05 am)! So, I'm not sure that this was stored in UTC time.

And one more thing.

Usual datetime field, I have set in admin this date: 2014-10-25 18:00:00

Id displayed in admin Oct. **25**, 2014, 6 p.m.

But select from DB show me:

2014-10-**26** 08:00:00.0

So, I definitely do not understand what's going on. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically what happens is that time is stored in database using the timestamp, but displays the time using timezone specified in your database, which is unless manually changed is the timezone of the machine. But since you specify a different timezone in django, django will adjust the difference. So what you need to do is  change the timezone in db to UTC (process differs depending on the engine)

The way I prefer to do it is leaving database timezone unchanged, specify 'UTC' in django settings, and then whenever displaying time to user, using some javascript convert it to local users time.

**Edit**

Didn't notice before that you are using PostgreSQL. I think you can just change timezone in postgresql.conf or change the TimeZone variable to UTC in database

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#postgresql) implies that, with `USE_TZ = True`, Django will always store the time zone in UTC: "The PostgreSQL backend stores datetimes as timestamp with time zone. In practice, this means it converts datetimes from the connection’s time zone to UTC on storage, and from UTC to the connection’s time zone on retrieval." So it shouldn't be necessary to change any PostgreSQL settings.

Comment: Actually I said it wrong, it does save the timestamp, but whenever you do a query it will display time using the timezone specified in the database settings. That's why you would have to change the setting in order to see UTC timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I think Alexey Kuleshevich answers the first part of your question: When you do the manual `select`, PostgreSQL is displaying the timestamp in the timezone configured on the database. That doesn't affect Django, though, which is behaving according to the documentation.

As for the second part of your question: When you enter a datetime value in a form, Django interprets it in the *current time zone*, which by default is the same as your `TIME_ZONE` setting. So when you enter 6pm in the admin, Django interprets that as being 6pm PST, and stores it as 1am UTC (the next day). The database is then displaying that as 8am local time (the next day).